# Como pegar informações de clima e tempo?

Tags: json, web-service

Me deparei com um problema que gostaria de ver se pode ser solucionado de maneira **similar ao dos correios**. Quando se tem um cep pode-se resgatar de um web service outros dados, como o endereço e a cidade desse cep informado.

Em relação ao clima, existe alguma forma de com informações do lugar pegar a temperatura da previsão do tempo, o horário e a temperatura atual daquele lugar(a intenção depois era estilizar o css dessa parte da página para deixar um visual agradável)?

Comment: Existem vários widgets no site do Climatempo e do Tempo Agora. Dá uma pesquisada.

Comment: mas eu não queria algo pronto Diego, como deixei claro na pergunta, queria pegar as informações via json por exemplo, algo similar como se faz nos correios, para depois eu manipular e criar meu próprio widget, mas vou dar uma olhada nesses sites também para ver como é.

Comment: "ver se pode ser solucionado de maneira similar ao dos correios" - justamente, fazer um crawler próprio pode ser o caminho. Precisa ver se a licença do site permite. "Não posso nem negar nem confirmar" que eu faço isso atualmente com uma fonte de qualidade, mas de qq forma eu cito a fonte no resultado final, imagino que não tenha problemas com a "licença" dessa forma kkk.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Você consegue essas informações através de APIs dos serviços de meteorologia, como a do [Yahoo!](https://developer.yahoo.com/weather/)

Criei e testei um exemplo de utilização, como mostrado abaixo:

```
<script>
    var callbackFunction = function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    };
</script>

<script src="https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select * from weather.forecast where woeid in (select woeid from geo.places(1) where text='são paulo, sp')&format=json&callback=callbackFunction"></script>
```

Onde:

- **format**: é o tipo de dado que será retornado, podendo ser JSON ou XML;
- **callback**: é a função que irá tratar a resposta da sua requisição.

Você também pode adicionar

```
and u = 'c'
```

na cláusula WHERE para alterar para o sistema métrico e a escala para Celsius.

Caso seja somente uma cidade, você pode pesquisar o WOEID antes para melhorar o tempo de resposta.

Por exemplo, para São Paulo capital,

http://woeid.rosselliot.co.nz/lookup/sao%20paulo

Iria retornar 455827, onde a consulta final seria:

```
select * from weather.forecast where woeid = 455827&format=json&callback=callbackFunction
```

Existe este [site](https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/?q=select%20*%20from%20weather.forecast%20where%20woeid%20in%20(select%20woeid%20from%20geo.places(1)%20where%20text%3D%22nome%2C%20ak%22)&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys#h=select%20*%20from%20weather.forecast%20where%20woeid%20in%20(select%20woeid%20from%20geo.places(1)%20where%20text%3D's%C3%A3o%20paulo%2C%20sp')), próprio do Yahoo!, onde você pode testar a sua YQL (Yahoo Query Language).

Vale dizer que de acordo com a API do Yahoo, o limite de consultas diárias é de 2 mil requisições, e fique atento aos termos de uso, onde só pode ser utilizada por indivíduos, empresas sem fins lucrativos e uso não comercial.

---

Lembre-se que a API do Yahoo! é só uma das soluções, caso ela não atenda à suas necessidades, pode pesquisar por 'weather api' ou 'previsão tempo api'.

Comment: vou testar essa solução silvalexandre e depois falo se consegui usar

Comment: Demorei para ver rs, mas tá funcionando direitinho!

Answer (score 5):

Achei esta 'API' que retorna os seguintes dados:

```
{
 "cidade":"Sao Paulo - SP",
 "agora":{
  "data_hora":"08\/11\/2013 - 19:59",
  "descricao":"Muito Nublado (noite)",
  "temperatura":"19",
  "humidade":"73%",
  "visibilidade":"9,99 km",
  "vento_velocidade":"20,92 km\/h",
  "vento_direcao":"SE",
  "pressao":"1.015,92 mBar",
  "pressao_status":"subindo",
  "nascer_do_sol":"6:16 am",
  "por_do_sol":"7:25 pm",
  "imagem":"http:\/\/developers.agenciaideias.com.br\/images\/tempo\/27.png"
 },
 "previsoes":[
  {
   "data":"Sexta - 08\/11\/2013",
   "descricao":"Parcialmente Nublado (noite)",
   "temperatura_max":"23",
   "temperatura_min":"16",
   "imagem":"http:\/\/developers.agenciaideias.com.br\/images\/tempo\/29.png"
  },
  {
   "data":"S\u00e1bado - 09\/11\/2013",
   "descricao":"Tempo Bom (dia)",
   "temperatura_max":"27",
   "temperatura_min":"18",
   "imagem":"http:\/\/developers.agenciaideias.com.br\/images\/tempo\/34.png"
  },
  {
   "data":"Domingo - 10\/11\/2013",
   "descricao":"Ensolarado",
   "temperatura_max":"29",
   "temperatura_min":"21",
   "imagem":"http:\/\/developers.agenciaideias.com.br\/images\/tempo\/32.png"
  },
  {
   "data":"Segunda - 11\/11\/2013",
   "descricao":"Parcialmente Nublado (dia)",
   "temperatura_max":"32",
   "temperatura_min":"23",
   "imagem":"http:\/\/developers.agenciaideias.com.br\/images\/tempo\/30.png"
  },
  {
   "data":"Ter\u00e7a - 12\/11\/2013",
   "descricao":"Parcialmente Nublado (dia)",
   "temperatura_max":"30",
   "temperatura_min":"19",
   "imagem":"http:\/\/developers.agenciaideias.com.br\/images\/tempo\/30.png"
  }
 ]
}
```

**Segue a url:**
http://developers.agenciaideias.com.br/tempo

Testei a requisição descrita na documentação, com Angularjs, e retornou tudo certinho.  =)

Comment: Essa tal agência tem "api" pra um monte de coisa e não diz as fontes de dados. Não posso afirmar isso, mas me dá impressão de ser uma mera coleção de dados de terceiros obtidos por _crawlers_. E _crawlers_ costumam quebrar quando a fonte original muda de estrutura, além de não necessariamente respeitar as regras de uso da origem. Provavelmente eu nunca usaria uma solução dessas (agora, se eu estiver enganado, basta me apontarem onde está essa informação, que eu mudo de idéia, e ainda faço um elogio pela diversidade de informações).

Comment: Sem contar que não está funcionando mais rs... pelo menos não hoje

Comment: @Bacco o que seria `crawlers`?

Comment: @JorgeMatheus também chamados de scrapers, depende do contexto. São aplicações que acessam os dados como se fossem usuários normais navegando no site ou aplicação, e retiram os dados das páginas via operações de strings. Como não é um processo "oficial", e as páginas sempre mudam, dependem de constante atualização de quem fez o crawler, e muitas vezes violam a permissão de uso do site original.

Answer (score 5):

A Climatempo (empresa brasileira de meteorologia) lançou uma API em 2017, você consegue pregar a previsão de forma grátis..

O site é https://advisor.climatempo.com.br

Lá tem toda a documentação. É só entrar com seu "Facebook", "Google" ou "Github", gerar um token e fazer a requisição via GET.

Comment: Excelente colaboração Vitor! Muito bom mesmo :)

Answer (score 2):

Se for via programação com c# recomendo utilizar o Html Agility Pack, com ele voce pode dizer a origem da informação (Site) e informar ao codigo em qual div esta a informação que você quer podendo utilizar para diversos fins, eu por exemplo utilizei para pegar os resultados da mega sena.

http://html-agility-pack.net/?z=codeplex

Answer (score 1):

Uma alternativa JSON é: http://webservice.seriesanalysis.com/moment/linhares_es

só trocar o nome da cidade seguido do estado. Tirar acentos, exemplo:

```
linhares_es,
saopaulo_sp,
vitoria_es,
riodejaneiro_rj
```

Comment: Não consigo consumir dados dessa url

Answer (score 1):

Baseado na resposta do silvalexandre
Usa o link antes para descobrir o woeid do seu local

```
    select woeid from geo.places(1) where text='são paulo, sp'
```

**Javascript**
Chama a lib jquery e

```
    <script>
    $.get('https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql',{
        q:'select * from weather.forecast where woeid in (455822)',
        format:'json'
    },function (res) {
        if(res){
            umi = res.query.results.channel.atmosphere.humidity;
            temp = res.query.results.channel.item.condition.temp;

            temp = Math.round((temp-32)/1.8); //F to C

            console.log(temp,umi);
        }
    },'json');
    </script>
```

**PHP**

```
$cont = file_get_contents("https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20weather.forecast%20where%20woeid%20in%20(455822)&format=json");

$cont = json_decode($cont,1);

$umi = $cont['query']['results']['channel']['atmosphere']['humidity'];
$temp = $cont['query']['results']['channel']['item']['condition']['temp'];

$temp = intval( ($temp - 32) /1.8 ); //F to C

echo $umi." ".$temp;
```