# API gratuita para Histórico climatológico

Tags: python, api, plotly

> Como já expliquei para o Guilherme nos comentários, eu deixo bem claro na minha pergunta que quero um HISTÓRICO climatológico. A pergunta indicada como duplicata NÃO mostra como recuperar HISTÓRICO climatológico. Por favor, tentem ler a pergunta antes de marcar duplicata, é uma falta de respeito marcar duplicata de uma pergunta sem antes ler a mesma.

Olá, estou brincando um pouco com a biblioteca `python` *plotly* e gostaria de tentar relacionar alguns dados históricos de previsão do tempo (chuvas, temperatura etc) com um conjunto de dados que já possuo.

Porém ainda não consegui achar nenhuma API que me forneça dados climatológicos históricos de uma cidade ou região de forma gratuita.

Existe alguma API que me forneça isso (dados climatológicos históricos) de forma gratuita?

O formato pode ser json, XML, não importa muito, desde que eu consiga acessar esses dados com *Python* está ótimo.

**EDIT:** A questao apontada como duplicata não é sobre historico de previsões do tempo e sim sobre previsões do tempo. O que eu preciso é do historico de previsoes de uma localidade.

Comment: Talvez no [site do INMET](http://www.inmet.gov.br/portal/).

Comment: Nao entendi direito como usar urllib e jsonparser pra conseguir o historico, nas respostas desse outro topico tem apenas chamadas que retornam previsões do tempo (pode ser que eu tenha sido bem "noob" e nao tenha achado onde ver o historico), se for esse o caso por favor me ilumine!

Comment: Percebi que houve mais uma marcação de duplicata, já li umas 10 vezes esse outro tópico que o @GuilhermeNascimento indicou pra tentar encontrar onde explica a forma de recuperar o HISTÓRICO climatológico mas não encontrei nada. Fica a dúvida se eu sou extremamente "tapado" ou se as pessoas marcam duplicata sem ao menos ler as perguntas.

Comment: Possivel duplicata indica "possivel", não significa que é.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento correto, não sei se é possível mas seria legal então desmarcar a questão como duplicata e apagar seu comentário de duplicata, Obrigado.

Comment: Você leu a parte que escrevi *"basta usar o urllib e um jsonparser"*? A tua pergunta é um pedido de serviço, se não é dup é offtopic. Agora se a dificuldade for no teu código python então o sentido muda e passa a ser on-topic.

Comment: Se usar a API que dessa resposta https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/117122/3635 com urllib (python), vai conseguir facilmente pegar os resultados.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento mas de onde vêm esses dados? Como monto uma query no YQL pra pegar a temperatura/humidade do ar de 2015 por exemplo, por lá eu consigo a previsão, assim como consigo pela openweathermap, mas dados históricos eu sinceramente não consigo encontrar. A parte de urllib/jsonparser, até onde eu sei, seria util apenas se eu tivesse os dados, mas eu não tenho e é exatamente isso que eu estou procurando

Comment: Agora de uma pergunta generica vocÊ esta tornando a duvida bem mais complexa, recomendo que edite sua pergunta, pois claramente o que você quer é muito além de indicarem APIs, este site não é para indiciar serviços e etc, se sua duvida é pegar a temperatura de uma data especifica .... PS: o urllib é para baixar os dados da API ;)

Comment: Não foi minha intenção deixar a duvida complexa. O exemplo foi apenas para tentar te ajudar a entender o que eu quero. O foco é: "*Uma API que forneça dados históricos climatológicos*. Como usar a API, como vou recuperar esses dados, isso eu me viro e é questão pra outra pergunta caso eu não consiga. Nesse tópico a única coisa que quero é a bendita API com históricos climatológicos. Isso é bem difícil de achar, se é que existe. Por isso postei aqui, já pesquisei em dezenas de sites e nas comunidades brasileira e gringa do SO, nada fornece o que preciso de forma gratuita.

Comment: Qual api que vc disse que tem os dados mas não consegue pegar?

Comment: openweathermap, é so ir em bulk history ou history, qualquer uma das 2 me serviria, mas nao consigo usar pois é pago e pelo que pesquisei não tem "conta de estudante"

Comment: Então o problema não era "pegar" e sim a questão de ser pago -.- podia ter falado antes né? Teria poupado algum tempo de entendimento do pessoal. Tá vou ver se encontro algo e te mando, pode ser? ;)

Comment: blza, muito obrigado!

Comment: Se você precisa de um **histórico** climático pra determinada região, já que não acha uma API gratuita que te de um histórico, você pode criar uma tabela por exemplo, que todo dia é alimentada usando um cronjob com o clima daquele dia

Comment: @MarceloBoni é exatamente isso que eu comecei a fazer, infelizmente vou ter que montar o meu proprio historico se não quiser pagar... E obrigado pela ajuda! To vendo uns negocio sobre aquele django-crontab pra ficar coletando esses dados

Answer (score 4):

### [Openweathermap:](http://openweathermap.org/api)

"Nosa API é simples, limpa e **digratis**. Nós oferecemos suporte em alto nível (planos pagos). Para acesso a API, voce precisa criar uma conta para obter um API Key."

[image: Openweathermap]

[Link para o site.](http://openweathermap.org/api)

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta @Sidon porem a openweathermap cobra 10 doletas pra fornecer o historico de uma localização :/

Comment: Então a proprganda é enganosa? No texto inicial da pagina diz que é free e só cobra pelo suporte.

Comment: hahaha, se dizem que só cobram pelo suporte é propaganda enganosa sim. A API no geral, pra ver previsões de tempo é grátis sim, mas histórico infelizmente não, dei uma BOA pesquisada já pela internet e achei alguns sites já que fornecem o que eu quero, mas todos são pagos  =/

Comment: Eu já usei esse serviço a algum tempo (menos de dois anos) e, sim, era de graça qq acesso, lembro que era meio complexo, mas era **digratis** sim. Devem ter mudado a pouco tempo.